# How to distribute gcc compiler binaries?

Tags: gcc

I want to distribute a gcc compiler within our company. I built required version from the sources, installed it in specified directory on my machine (all machines, btw, have the same architecture). I expected that I can put contents of this directory on the server and with the next update all my colleagues will get a new compiler.

But of course that doesn't work.

I tried to search for a ready solution for the linux but couldn't find anything.

Right now if I try to compile some basic program I get an error:

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory.

But this file was build and indeed resides in one of the subfolders of main install directory. I tried to explicitly specify the path to this subprogramm using `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` and `COMPILER_PATH` environment variables but with no luck.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: You copied over the `gcc` binary, but did you copy over the programs it depends on, and the header files it provides for the programs it compiles?

Comment: Yes, I copied the entire installation folder with all binaries and includes.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to work (try moving the installation around locally on your machine to check).

Comment: On my machine everything works fine - maybe because I have multiple installations of gcc or some environment variables are set as expected.

Comment: Use strace to figure out where it is looking for those binaries.